# Remove array elements with value of ""

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array:

```
var x = ["happy", "", "sad", ""];
```

How do I convert it to:

```
["happy","sad"];
```

---

Similarly, how do I convert this array:

```
var y = ["happy", ""];
```

to:

```
["happy"];
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: In addition to the answers, you could also use `array = array.filter(String)` - it should filter out empty strings

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Like this:

```
var x = ["happy", "", "sad", ""];
x = x.filter(function(v){
    return v !== "";
});
```

You can also do `return v;` but that would also filter out `false`, `null`, `0`, `NaN` or anything *falsy* apart from `""`.

The above filters out all `""` from your array leaving only `"happy"` and `"sad"`.

**Update:** String method returns the argument passed to it in it's String representation. So it will return `""` for `""`, which is *falsey*. SO you can just do

```
x = x.filter(String);
```

Comment: what "i" is doing here.. for indexing ?

Comment: @vaibhav yeah. Its not needed though

Comment: I wanted to suggest an edit to change `!=` to `!==`, except edits need to be 6+ characters long. It is better to always use `===` and `!==` (==, != have implicit conversions that break the transitivity of equality). Here especially it might end up filtering out `false` values as well.

Comment: @EyasSH, incorporated. Thanks :)

Comment: @user3553493, glad to have helped you :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `Array.prototype.filter`

```
array = array.filter(function (elem) { return elem; });
```

You could also do `elem !== ""` if you don't want to filter out `false`, `null`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For your array you can use simple:

```
x = x.filter(Boolean);
```

This would filter also `null`, `undefined`, `false`, `0` values